# User Login credential doesn't show up in the landing page(Homepage) after logging in

Tags: android

I got user-login template from github. I modified it a bit to suit my need but didn't altered any important code.

Problem 1: If I register and login, the page goes to activity_main class(landing page) and my login credentials(name & email) are shown. But if I log out and logging again the credentials are not shown on the landing page. First time it shows next time never.

Problem 2: If I register a new ID but login with any old already registered ID (immediately after registering new), landing page shows the credential of newly register ID. After that again it won't show up if I log in with any ID.

What I want to Happen: User credential to be shown on landing page whenever he logs in.Also prob 2nd to be fixed.

Any help would be appreciated guys.

login page code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this, Activity_Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Activity_Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                Config_URL.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this,
                                Activity_Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Register page code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        inputNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Register.this,
                    Activity_Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                String number = inputNumber.getText().toString();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !number.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password, number);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Activity_Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password, final String number) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                Config_URL.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Activity_Register.this,
                                Activity_Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "register");
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("number", number);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Main activity page code:

```
public class Activity_Main extends Activity {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    public Button booknow;
    public void init(){
        booknow= (Button) findViewById(R.id.booknow);
        booknow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent toy = new Intent(Activity_Main.this,BikeEntryActivity.class);
                startActivity(toy);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Logout button click event
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Main.this, Activity_Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }



    }
```

Comment: You are not saving anything to database on successful login. Therefore user details are empty.

Comment: Could you plz explain it a bit. where I need to modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 1, when you logout, you are deleting users by calling                    db.deleteUsers();
When you login again, you need to call     db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at); as you did for registration.

The same applies for problem 2.

UPDATE:

```
       ....
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

               //You need to save the user here before launching main activity.
                  db.addUser(name,email);//or whatever method you use to save user.


                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this,
                            Activity_Main.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
```

Comment: I tried not to call db.deleteUsers(); while logging out but it didn't fixed the prob..I might be doing something wrong. I am not that experienced in android. It would be nice of you if you can show me how to do it in above code. Help plz.

Comment: Problem 1 was solved, as you said I was deleting login data by calling by calling db.deleteUsers(); . So I removed this and now user data is there.

Comment: if (!error) {
//to save the usr
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);     I used this as you said but application stops when I press login.

Comment: Can I see the response of your LOGIN API?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void helper.SQLiteHandler.addUser(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Your db object is null. You need initialize it before using. Add this line  db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext()); before if(!error).....

Comment: It fixed the crashing. But Problem 2 still exist. last user logged in data still remains if new user logs in. any way Thanks for helping me out so religiously. As it solved one of my prob, I am marking it an answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. For problem 2, remove  the line db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at); from the registerUser() method in your Register page code. It is no more needed since you are calling the login page again.